# Does the "User Agent" header value ever change?

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, user-agent, device-detection

I am researching methods for detecting mobile devices. Let me preface this by stating that I already know about the [WURFL file](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/). One of the other options I am considering is maintaining a list of 'User Agent' header values in-house.

**Has anyone seen these header values change for a specific device?** I know new ones will pop up as new devices hit the market, but I am more concerned with existing values changing on me.

Comment: Could not understand the question clearly. Can you elaborate your question please? What is "user agent for a specific device", define "specific device" and give an example of it. Add your aim here too. Maybe you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking but; if a device/phone already on the market no it wouldn't change largely but you should expect change as phone/device gets service updates.
goog think about is WURFL that it will try to match the device to a more generic model.

There may be 5 different iPhone 3 S but WURFL would match all as iPhone 3 S

It is hard work to maintain your own user agent list on your own.